# Disabling Trackpad while typing does not work

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, trackpad

---

I installed Ubuntu 12.04LTS on my Lenovo Thinkpad Edge 320 and the Option to disable the trackpad while typing does not work.
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use syndaemon to automatically disable touchpad while typing.

An example would be:

`syndaemon -i -K -R -t -d`

-i specifies how many seconds after last key press before enabling the touchpad (default is 2 seconds)

-K allows modifiers such as Shift and Alt

-R uses XRecord for detecting keyboard activity instead of polling

-t only disables tapping and scrolling but allows mouse movement

-d will start syndaemon as a daemon

you can see all of the options on

`man syndaemon`

Comment: so when i write "syndaemon -i 0.5" i won't get a new command line. It works but only until i close the Terminal. It looks like it is stuck in a loop after i send the command.

Comment: @Daniel You may try running it with ` &` at the end so that it's run in the background. As for the terminal closing problem, if you save the command in a simple script file and add it to the starting apps, I think it should do the thing. Perhaps adding something like `sleep 15` before the command may be necessary.

Comment: @Daniel did you try 'syndaemon -i 0.5 -d' ? The -d should start it as a daemon and run in background